# Is it required to un-register the events of all UI Elements to reduce memory leak? 

Tags: memory-leaks, windows-phone-7

i read [Here](http://10rem.net/blog/2012/02/01/event-handler-memory-leaks-unwiring-events-and-the-weakeventmanager-in-wpf-45?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20PeteBrown-WindowsClient%20%28Pete%20Brown%27s%20Blog%20%3a%20WindowsClient%29&utm_content=Google%20International)
 and bit confused about the unregistering events. means i have button and registered for click event whether its required unregitser click event explicitly in page unload event.
Because all most UI elements will registered for some of the events.

In the model and viewmodel i can unregistered event explicitly (like loadCompleted)

Is it required to un-register the events of all UI Elements to reduce memory leak?

Comment: @ Erno: It it required to un-register the events to reduce memory leak for all UI Elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to unregister eventhandlers that would keep the View in memory.

So if you Keep the ViewModel object (e.g. to pass it on to another view) any binding between the View and ViewModel might keep the View in memory (reachable). If you do not keep the ViewModel you ar enot in danger of this. (Yet be very certain that you do not keep a reference to the ViewModel)

[A good description of this problem (and solutions) can be found here](http://10rem.net/blog/2012/02/01/event-handler-memory-leaks-unwiring-events-and-the-weakeventmanager-in-wpf-45)

Comment: I read that article but cionfused. please esure its reuqired unregister the Click event of button explicitely.?

Comment: If the Click handler is in the code behind of the View; there is no problem, you do not need to unregister. If you use Binding, e.g., by binding the Command property of the button to the ViewModel, you might need to unregister this binding.